# How can I create a PDF link to the last named version of a Google Document?

Tags: rest, url, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a live document which is available for download on my website (a manual for a piece of equipment). I want to be able to make changes without these minor changes being visible to the user and so thought that using named versions would be ideal. But I can't see a way to link to the most recent named version.

I'm sure I could use Google Script to create a second document and duplicate into it every time I name the version, but I was thinking there should be an easier way.

The URL I'm currently using is in the following format.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/{Document ID}/export?format=pdf
```

This works well as long as I don't make changes to the document.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, the name of a named version can't be retrieved using the G Suite APIs.*

#### More Information:

The Docs API itself doesn't have methods that allow access to revisions, and while the Drive API does, there isn't a resource representation of the name so the revisions can't be identified by name itself.

#### Workaround:

If the version you need is the latest version, you can use the Drive API `Revisions: list` method to retrieve the latest revision and get an export link to that from the `exportLinks` property of the resource response:

```js
function getExportLink() {
  var fileId = "<your-file-id>";
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var latestRevision = revisions.items[(revisions.items.length - 1)];
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=";
  var revision = "&revision=" + latestRevision.id;
  var format = "&exportFormat=pdf";
  
  return url + fileId + revision + format;
}
```

Note: you have to use the Advanced Drive Service v2 to get Revisions from within Apps Script - to activate this navigate to `Resources > Advanced Google Services...` and click the switch next to `Drive API` so that it says `on` and turns green.

#### References:

- [Google Documents API Reference](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest)
- [Download and publish file revisions - Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions)
- [Google Drive API Revisions Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions#methods)
- [Google Drive API `Revisions: list` method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)

Comment: This is really close, but there permissions on the Drive file don't seem to match the Docs.
This link: 
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id={Docs ID}&revision=13&exportFormat=pdf
Doesn't work for external users, while this link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/{Docs ID}/export?format=pdf
Works no problems provided the permissions are set.

Comment: I tried adding this line: DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); But no luck.