# Copy file revisions to new file Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

Im trying to copy a file using python Google Drive api. Is there a way to copy a file with its revisions, or to update the copied file with the old files revisions?

Comment: welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code and any research you have done.

Answer (score 1):

- The revisions are bound to a certain file with a certain Id - the one that has been revised
- When you create a new file, its revision history is empty. Revisions are not part of the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) and they are readonly, so unfortunately you cannot copy or manually assign an existing revisions to a new file.
- If the users of the new file are interested in the revision history, you can e.g. export it as a pdf -  as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59138268/11599789).